# Creating a Game Engine with a C++ Compiler?

Tags: opengl

I'm thinking of creating a Game Engine with a C++ Compiler using OpenGL but I don't know how to create a compiler in an application. Do I have to write the compiler? or could I use (for example) the Visual C++ Compiler?

Comment: don't think this is game dev related. Sameh Hany needs a basic introduction to compiling stuff with C++... or how C++ applications are built in general, which I think belongs on SO.

Comment: Really, with a question like that, I honestly doubt you're ready to make games. Start a little smaller; you'll get to games eventually (if you are persistent, that is). I'm not trying to be a jerk or anything, but you obviously are just getting started with programming.

Comment: Does he ask to get a compiler embedded into an application?

Comment: Guys, there's no reason to downvote and hate, just answer the question!

Comment: @bobobobo, there isn't any "hating" going on here - in fact, Paul gave as *polite* an answer as is possible, given the poor question. Giving someone constructive criticism, or any kind of *negative* feedback, *isn't* the same thing as "hating". And poor questions should be downvoted - it's part of how these sites work.

Comment: @bobobobo Sameh has a lack of knowledge (or research) of the elements at hand. As a side effect of this question unfortunately being nonsense, it's not useful. That matches 2/3 of the downvote tooltip. None of this is personal, so how can this possibly be hate?

Answer (score 6):

The only reason that I can see for including a compiler in an application is that you wish users to be able to write their own code in C++ which is compiled, linked, and executed at runtime. This isn't a brilliant idea, and in fact there is a common game engine technique called scripting that allows users to do write their own code and have it executed.

A short extract from Jason Gregory's [Game Engine Architecture (third edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814135) from page 794 can be found below:

> A scripting language can be defined as a programming language whose primary purpose is to permit users to control and customise the behaviour of a software application.

...

> In the context of game engines, a scripting language is a high level, relatively easy-to-use programming language that provides its users with convenient access to most of the commonly used features of the engine. As such, a scripting language can be used by programmers and non-programmers alike to develop a new game or to customise - or "mod" - an existing game.

A short list of benefits of scripting:

- You can only expose the parts of the engine to the scripting system that you want to.
- The scripts are loaded at runtime and can be edited off-line without the engine needing to be recompiled.
- They help support rapid iteration times and are sometimes quite lightweight.

I would suggest you look into adding scripting functionality as this would be a better solution to your problem. There are many scripting related questions on gamedev.stackexchange to get you started!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can (and in my opinion should!) use the Visual C++ compiler. It is currently one of the best compilers out there.

Furthermore, while it is very interesting to write your own compiler, it's not very wise to use it for speed-critical applications like games.

Comment: Maybe, but if he wants it to be cross platform using another compiler could be helpfull.

Comment: A reasonable answer.